# Creating Mongoid embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid for the first time. I want to store a collection of emails that have a subject, body, and arrays of to, cc, and bcc recipients. Example:

```
{to: [{email: 'andrew@example.com', name: 'Andrew'}], cc: ...
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to model this data using Mongoid. I think the term for these are called embedded documents, but everything I've tried does not seem to work right. How do I create my models correctly with Mongoid?

Comment: Have you read the docs? It explains how to do this very clearly: http://mongoid.org/docs/documents.html

Comment: This link is better, I think: http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html

Comment: Looks simple until you try to do what you want. It looks like an Email class which contains an embeds_many :recipients, :as => :to, and a Recipient class with an :embedded_in :to looks like what it recommends but it just doesn't look right.

Comment: My co-worker posted this same question, only better formatted, so please help answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183544/mongoid-same-embedded-documents-types-for-different-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. You can specify class name if you want to reuse a class for multiple fields:

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :to_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"
  embeds_many :cc_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"
  embeds_many :bcc_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"    
  embeds_one :from, :class_name => "Recipient"

  field :subject, type: String
  field :body_text, type: String
  field :body_html, type: String
end

class Recipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end
```