# Mongoid same embedded documents types for different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am attempting to add embedded documents. I know this syntax is wrong but it demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :recipients, as: :to
  embeds_many :recipients, as: :cc
  embeds_many :recipients, as: :bcc

  field :from, type: String
  field :subject, type: String
  field :body, type: String
end

class Recipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end
```

The code sample below works, but I am trying to avoid the code duplication.

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :to_recipients
  embeds_many :cc_recipients
  embeds_many :bcc_recipients

  field :from, type: String
  field :subject, type: String
  field :body, type: String
end

class ToRecipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end

class CcRecipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end

class BccRecipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end
```

Anyone know of a clean way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the best answer!

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :to_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"
  embeds_many :cc_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"
  embeds_many :bcc_recipients, :class_name => "Recipient"    
  embeds_one :from, :class_name => "Recipient"

  field :subject, type: String
  field :body_text, type: String
  field :body_html, type: String
end

class Recipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this may be the best solution

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :to_recipients
  embeds_many :cc_recipients
  embeds_many :bcc_recipients

  field :from, type: String
  field :subject, type: String
  field :body_text, type: String
  field :body_html, type: String
end

class Recipient
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_address, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  validates :email_address, :presence => true
  embedded_in :emails
end


class ToRecipient < Recipient; end
class CcRecipient < Recipient; end
class BccRecipient < Recipient; end
```